# How to return output parameter from stored procedure and catch/handle in C#?

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. The stored procedure has an output parameter of type `varchar(15)`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_Authenticate]
    (@username int, 
     @password varchar(25),
     @Error varchar(15) output)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @count INT

    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM loginmaster 
                  WHERE userid = @userid AND password = @password)

    IF (@count = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Error = 'Error1'
    END
END
```

When I run the stored procedure from SSMS, it is working properly, but when I call the stored procedure from C#, with the help of ExecuteScalar, it is not working as expected. `ExecuteScalar` always returns null. If the same same thing I do with `ExecuteNonQuery`, it is working properly. `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for insert/update. `ExeuteNonQuery` returns number of row affected rows as int value:

```
Int rowaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Normally I check if `rowaffected` is greater than 0, take value output parameter.

```
if(rowaffected  > 0)
{
  string s = sqlparameterError.value.Tostring()
}
```

Here how can I check? `rowaffected` is always -1. Is it right way to check it?

I have changed my code. I removed output parameter. I have created a variable and taken in select. With the help of `ExecuteScalar` I am able to get value of it.

Modified stored procedure is like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_Authenticate]
    (@username int,   
     @password varchar(25))
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @count INT 
    DECLARE @Error VARCHAR(15) 

    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM loginmaster 
                  WHERE userid = @userid and password = @password)

    IF (@count = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Error = 'Error1'
    END

    SELECT @Error AS Error
END
```

Comment: Did you try this `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` and after that `cmd.Parameters["@Error"].Value` ?

Comment: Yes Afnan,I have done that.

Comment: is it working with this ?

Comment: how do you call the sp from your c#-code? recordsaffected [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected(v=vs.110).aspx) states: number of rows inserted or deleted. you are doing a count, no insert or delete. recordsaffected is not the way to get your count.

Comment: ExecuteScalar is defined to return the first result value of the first dataset selected. It does not return output parameters (of which there may be more then one). So this behaviour (the null result) is expected.

Answer (score 2):

After `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` you can get your output parameter like this :

```
cmd.Parameters["@Error"].Value
```

Comment: Possibly you need to define the parameter before you execute the command, and set it's [Direction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx) to `Output`.